# using mysql function select now() with jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to execute the following mysql query using jdbc driver.

query:-

```
UPDATE cp_game_config SET end_date=(SELECT NOW()+500) WHERE STATUS='buddy.created' ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

the query is working effectively when i run it through sqlyog.
but my objective is to run the query using jdbc driver.
i have build a string called query builder.
the value of query builder is:

```
UPDATE cardplay_poker.cp_game_config SET end_date=  '(SELECT NOW()+500)'where STATUS=  'buddy.created'  ORDER BY start_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

but when i am running the program it throws error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '(SELECT NOW()+500)' for column 'end_date'
```

please help.

Comment: Please include the Java code which generated this error.  It looks like a typo question, but might be more than this.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from `'(SELECT NOW()+500)'` .

Comment: You should be using PreparedStatement and binding variables, not constructing query strings this way.

Comment: You do not need a subquery to add 500 to now().

Comment: You are trying to set the **string** value `'(SELECT NOW()+500)'` (note the presence of single quotes), not the datetime result of `(SELECT NOW() + 500)`. You are building your query incorrectly. Without your actual code we can't tell exactly what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Arnaud i am passing the query through json file. so everything needs to be in double quotes.then i am parsing the json file and storing the query in stringbuilder.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel cannot do that because my code is writtten in a way that it will add single quotes.but is there any other way to execute  (SELECT NOW()+500) function using single quotes??